# Natural exponential function: not surjective, but still right invertible?

Tags: calculus

The natural exponential function $f(x) = e^{x}$ is not surjective. It should then not be right invertible by the theorem "*f is right invertible iff f is surjective*".

But is not $g(y)=ln(y)$ its right inverse?

$f(g(y))=e^{ln(y)}=y$

Thanks.

Comment: Surjective on what codomain?

Comment: Why and how is this [set-theory]???

Comment: Surjective on the reals?

Comment: The expanded statement is: *$f : X \to Y$ is surjective* (i.e. $f[X]=Y$) *iff there is $g : Y \to X$ such that $f \circ g = \operatorname{id}_Y$*. Do you see what fails here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result you need (and the one you should have found in your basic textbooks) is:

$f(x) = e^x$ is bijective from $(-\infty, \infty)$ onto $(0,\infty)$.  Therefore the inverse function exists, a function from $(0,\infty)$ onto $(-\infty , \infty)$.